# Inconsistent slide margins in frame with allowframebreaks option in Beamer

Tags: beamer, margins

When I create a long beamer frame which is automatically splitted into slides by using `allowframebreaks` option, it has a little bigger vertical margin for the first slide. I would like to make it more consistent with the rest of the frame. I cannot find the reason of this behavior and a way to fix it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Comparison]

Comment: if you replace the backslashes with white space (to make a new paragraph instead of a line break), does the problem go away?

Comment: Yes, it happens with paragraphs and also with things like `printbibliography` that was the original command used when I've noticed it.

Comment: I could be misinterpreting something, but my document with each paragraph consisting of a single letter A and enough paragraphs to force the `allowframebreaks` option to take effect, I don't see the vertical offset you describe. There might be a pixel or two, or maybe none at all, but certainly not the nearly 50% of the baseline height you show with the backslashes.

Comment: I've checked this once again (replaced `\\ ` with double newlines, with `\par`s and with regular whitespaces) – the result is always the same, i.e. as in the screenshoot comparison above. I suppose that in my case `allowframebreaks` seems to redefine some dimensions when switching to second slide (I use 64-bit MiKTeX).

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277473/align-beamer-slides-with-frame-breaks

Comment: The issue is also addresses from the beamer maintainer (at least I think that it is related): https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/325

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been fixed in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/fd369b715b9c8738da88d1589785fe48ecff1031

The fix is included in beamer versions >= 3.54